# What is the smallest animal you can train to shoot a pistol or similar ranged weapon?

Tags: fauna

Pretty much title says it all.
It just needs to not be afraid of explosions and pull a trigger or other activation mechanism on command, if it understands by itself when to shoot, then even better. Doesn't have to aim or move around the weapon, it is fixed.. It just needs to pull the trigger.

Comment: Define "command". And define the circumstances, under which the animal should pull the trigger. You can teach rats to press a button when a bulb lights up (usually they get a treat), but I strongly doubt they are capable of assessing approaching targets and pulling the trigger all by themselves.

Comment: @Erik "fire now!"

Comment: So you include comprehension of audio commands. Which probably then limits your choice of animals and is a simple google search.

Comment: A praying mantis? Eyes specifically tailored to detect movement, track enemies. Reflexes that make a computer relay green with envy. Able to sit still and await the target for *hours* without getting impatient. And trigger design is normally made to match the shooter. It would be *trivial* to make a trigger much more sensitive, requiring just a tap.

Answer (score 2):

just my opinion (i dont know much about gun) assuming they use common gun trigger.

[image]

joke aside, snake can be trained or guide to at least, and i believe their constriction can help push the trigger, though i am not sure can they get used to the loud sound or vibration of the explosion or not.

otherwise i think monkey is a good choice, they can be trained even with audio command, and can hold or push the gun trigger at least, regarding not afraid of explosion i believe that they can be train to get used to the loud sound.

from:https://lifetimestock.com/media/18744

[image]

from:https://www.shutterstock.com/search/monkey+with+guns

[image]

from: https://www.stripes.com/blogs-archive/the-rumor-doctor/the-rumor-doctor-1.104348/is-photo-of-baboon-with-a-machine-gun-fake-1.111041#.X_SNq7hHNTc

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Insects are trainable](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-train-an-insect), and since you're allowing "other activation mechanisms", I'd suggest that you could stimulus-response train an ant or tiny beetle to walk onto stimulus = YES triggering mechanism. The size of the gun so activated is up to you!

Just put the triggering mechanism [under the little yellow ball](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZhu5-3ZmoE) and you can redefine the term "killer bee"!

Insects will serve your purpose well because their relatively simple nervous systems don't allow for higher emotions like "fear" and just from ordinary observation, insects don't seem to be particularly fazed by human made bangs like fireworks or gunshots.

Comment: Insects feel fear.  https://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/flies-experience-emotions-fear-and-might-offer-insight-how-brain-makes-feelings-10253201.html .  It may not be the same as the human experience of fear, but the results are the same.  Also, fear is not a "higher" emotion, it is the singular most basic and universal emotion in existence.  All of the other emotions are "higher" emotions.

Comment: @cowlinator -- I think at best what insects are "feeling" is nothing more than the need to move away from a stimulus. Fear is a very complex emotional state, and often an incorrect one at that! Insects just don't have the brain power to experience it.

Comment: Well, it's your word against a peer-reviewed paper in the National Library of Medicine.  "Flies' responses to repetitive visual threat stimuli express an internal state exhibiting canonical emotion primitives, possibly analogous to fear in mammals."  https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25981791/

Comment: @cowlinator -- I'll leave the scienticians to sort out the details. In the mean time...